# gcc on i386 architecture

Tags: gcc, makefile, i386

I'm trying to link some .o files with:

```
gcc -m32 send.o lib.o -o send
```

and i get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `send.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have installed 
libc6-i386
gcc-multilib
ia32-lib

Where could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You're not compiling. You're linking already compiled object files. It appears that send.o was compiled as an x86_64 object (without -m32). You cannot link a 64-bit executable from 32-bit object files.

Make sure all your object files are compiled in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Sorry, I just link them.I've tryed also without -m32, it is not working, I'm shure the files had been compiled on x86 architecture.

Comment: So then lib.o is ELF32, which is incompatible with 64-bit output.

Comment: What error message do you get when you link without -m32? What's the output of 'file send.o lib.o'?